# OrientDB query using GROUP BY

Tags: orientdb

The below query returns incorrect number of rows:

```
SELECT keyName.left(keyName.indexOf('_Configuration/')) AS keyValue, 
address.zip AS zip, 
customer_map AS customerMap 
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE customer_group = 'xyz' 
GROUP BY keyValue, customerMap, zip
```

where column datatypes are as the following:

```
keyName String 
address EMBEDDEDMAP 
customer_map EMBEDDEDMAP
```

However, if the GROUP BY is changed to use the column names instead of aliases, the query returns correct number of rows:

```
SELECT keyName.left(keyName.indexOf('_Configuration/')) AS keyValue, 
address.zip AS zip, 
customer_map AS customerMap 
FROM CUSTOMERS 
WHERE customer_group = 'xyz' 
GROUP BY keyValue, customer_map, address.zip
```

Interestingly, using an alias for `keyName.left(...)` does not affect GROUP BY, but a function like for example: 
 `ifnull(keyName, 'ABC) AS keyValue` 
makes the query to return incorrect number of rows.

Note that the first query does not give any errors/warnings, just returns incorrect number of rows. 
Is that expected behaviour of GROUP BY? 
Unfortunately OrientDB docs do not have too many details about GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

The query execution flow is as follows:

- find query target (indexes first, then fallback on cluster iterators)
- iterate over the target and filter based on WHERE condition (excluding conditions already matched by indexes)
- calculate projections on filtered records
- apply UNWIND and EXPAND
- apply Group By
- apply Order By
- apply SKIP and LIMIT

You can use

```
select keyValue,zip,customerMap from (SELECT keyName.left(keyName.indexOf('_Configuration/')) AS keyValue, 
address.zip AS zip, 
customer_map AS customerMap 
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE customer_group = 'xyz' )
GROUP BY keyValue, customerMap, zip
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I should have mentioned that we tried to use select from (select ...) GROUP BY keyValue, customerMap, zip, but on a table with 100,000+ rows, this query is extremely slow - there is a non-unique index on the customer_group column. Without the outer select the query is much faster. What are the rules for using GROUP BY? OrientDB doc says that only one column can be used in GROUP BY, but seems  that it works with more than one column.

Comment: Yes, it works with more column. You can see this link http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Tutorial-SQL.html#-group-by